# php array value gets replaced in loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, overriding

I just tried to loop through the fetched results of a database query and storing them in a new array. So my first attempt was this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name, uid, coordinates, address, timestamp FROM my_table WHERE uid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);

$stmt->execute();
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) 
{ 
    $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

$results = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $results[] = $row;

    echo "Results: <pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre><br />";
}
```

EDIT: It is a MySQL(i) Statement and $row itself is defined and contains the query data.

But the result was rather unexpected:

(Due to privacy measures I can only show you the timestamps but you can still see what I mean)

```
Results: Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => ---
        [uid] => ---
        [coordinates] => ---
        [address] => --
        [timestamp] => 1395607435.826
    )
)

Results: Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => ---
        [uid] => ---
        [coordinates] => ---
        [address] => ---
        [timestamp] => 1395607047.357
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => ---
        [uid] => ---
        [coordinates] => ---
        [address] => ---
        [timestamp] => 1395607047.357
    )
)

Results: Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => ---
        [uid] => ---
        [coordinates] => ---
        [address] => ---
        [timestamp] => 1395607158.907
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => ---
        [uid] => ---
        [coordinates] => ---
        [address] => ---
        [timestamp] => 1395607158.907
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => ---
        [uid] => ---
        [coordinates] => ---
        [address] => ---
        [timestamp] => 1395607158.907
    )
)
```

What am I missing? 
Why is the array getting overriden each time and not just appended?

Comment: Yes i know that but the question is why the already existing elements are replaced by new ones

Comment: This code shouldn't add *anything* since `$row` isn't being defined anywhere.

Comment: How can we help if we don't know how `$row` is set?

Comment: I added the rest of the query

Comment: `$row` is still not set anywhere.

Comment: @axxis It is. Including some by-reference shenanigans which most certainly are the cause of the problem here, but I can't be bothered to figure out how in detail.

Comment: What probably happens is that `$row` is a reference to something, so every time you add `$row` to the array, you add a reference to the db record. `$row` always points to the last record, so all your entries in the array show the last record.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
$results = array();
$i=0; // using this variable so that you can have a track of the index that you are in, if you do not wish to use this increment variable then you can remove it.
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $results[] = $row;

    $i++;
}


echo "Results: <pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre><br />";
```

Comment: It's better to have the display instructions outside the `while` loop, and `$i++` is redundant!!

Comment: @Relativity The main change here is the addition of the `$row =` to the `while` statement.

Comment: But wouldn't $row then just contain true and not the actual values?

Comment: as @someOne, suggested we can have the print_r() outside the while loop

Comment: @Relativity If the `$stmt` is a `PDOStatement` then the [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method returns a row, while there is some!!

Comment: check also the records in your database if they exists or not in the way you expect them to be in

Comment: @Relativity Then you should already have the result variables bound! [check](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)!!

Comment: Yes but the values are not the problem, just the fact that the array also overrides its previous values with the current row and not just the most recent

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I'll just use my workaround. If there should be anything more performant please let me know.

```
$results = array();
$index = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{   
    $data                = array();
    $data["name"]        = $row["name"];
    $data["uid"]         = $row["uid"];
    $data["coordinates"] = $row["coordinates"];
    $data["address"]     = $row["address"];
    $data["timestamp"]   = $row["timestamp"];

    $results[$index] = $data;
    $index++;
}
```